# How to configure Neovim clangd to find my files?

Tags: neovim, lazyvim

I've used LazyVim's mason to install clangd LSP, but it doesn't seem to work properly.
It can't find files in my workspace, so when I try to jump to declaration, it does nothing if the declaration is in the workspace (vs. the c++ std lib, which clangd able to find)

I managed to hack it by using `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=...workspace/include/`, but that means I need to do it manually - which makes no sense.

I also tried to disable the auto formatting - which can be done by "uf" - which toggles the "on save format" - but I want to get that on startup, not click it every time I open a new nvim session

Comment: Normally you need to create `compile_commands.json` with e.g. `make clean; bear -- make` or `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1`. See [the docs](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html#project-setup). The autoformatting is a bit of a different question.

Comment: I added the cmake flag - and got a `./build/compile_commands.json` file - It still doesn't seem to work. Copying the file to my workspace root directory solved the issue

Comment: You can add `--compile-commands-dir=…` to `clangd` as well.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? If the answer address your need maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: The save on format is unanswered, but as it is off topic, I'll accept the answer and maybe open another one dedicated to that. Thx

Comment: I believe I have an answer for that question too. Ask a separate question and I'll give you the answer ;-)

Comment: I'm too impatient. I have created the  [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42598/23502) for you :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a `compile_commands.json` in the root of my project.

I make sure it is the working directory (using [vim-rooter](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vim-root) may help for that) but I'm not sure it is a requirement.

The [documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/design/compile-commands#where-do-compile-commands-come-from) says that the `compile_commands.json` is searched next to the file and if not found searched in the parent folders until one is found (thanks to @Friedrich to pointing this to me).

The `compile_commands.json` would contains the instructions to build each of the `cpp` files.

For a project like:

```
._ project1
| |_ main.cpp
|
|_ project2
| |_ foo.cpp
| |
| |_ include
|   |_ foo.h
|
|_ compile_commands.json
```

e.g.(`compile_commands.json`):

```
[
  {
    "directory": "full/path/to/project1",
    "command": "clang++.exe -x c++ main.cpp -std=c++2b -DMYFLAG1 -DMYFLAG2 -Iinclude -I../project2/include",
    "file": "main.cpp"
  },
  {
    "directory": "full/path/to/project2",
    "command": "clang++.exe -x c++ foo.cpp -std=c++2b -DMYFLAG1 -DMYFLAG2 -Iinclude",
    "file": "foo.cpp"
  }
]
```

In order to debug your `compile_commands.json` the following command is helpful:

```
clangd --check=project2/foo.cpp
```

It allow to to verify that:

- The `compile_commands.json` is correctly identified
- The resulting compilation flag for the selected file (`project2/foo.cpp` in the example)

If that is too much work you could also only have a file (`compile_flags.txt`) with common compiler flags (it provides already some information about the available includes to clangd). It allow to navigate through the includes and to the declaration but not to the definition.

e.g. (`compile_flags.txt`):

```
-x
c++
-std=c++2b
-D
MYFLAG1
-D
MYFLAG2
-I
include
-I
../project2/include
```

Remarks:

- with `compile_command.json` the `gd` coc command (`<Plug>(coc-definition)`) goes to the implementation of the function (`.cpp` in general)
- with `compile_flags.txt` the `gd` coc command (`<Plug>(coc-definition)`) goes to the declaration of the function (`.h` in general)

It seems to me that the `gi` coc command (`<Plug>(coc-definition)`) is not implemented in the `coc-clangd`.

Comment: It should be called `compile_flags.txt` not `compiler_flags.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I have adapted the solution accordingly.