# How to disable autoformating on save on LazyVim?

Tags: neovim, formatting, lazyvim

On LazyVim when I save a cpp file it is automatically formatted.

It is possible to disable/enable it in the session using <kbd>Space</kbd>`uf`

But I would like to disable that autoformatting on save functionality by default.

How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The auto-formatting on save is a LazyVim functionality associated to the `nvim-lspconfig` plugin.

To disable it you have to create a lua file in `~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins` folder with the following content:

`~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/lazyvim.lua`

```
return {
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = {
      autoformat = false,
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I received a warning using the above answer. Looks like it should be set in

`~/.config/nvim/lua/config/options.lua`

```
vim.g.autoformat = false
```

Comment: That sets the vim option. What warning ? How does this affect lsp config?

Comment: `nvim-lspconfig.opts.autoformat` is deprecated. Please use 
    `vim.g.autoformat` instead
    
    # stacktrace:
      - /LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/util/plugin.lua:93 _in_ ****
      - vim/_editor.lua:0

Comment: Great answer, can confirm this works - if anyone is curious, LazyVim is setting that [here](https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim/blob/main/lua/lazyvim/config/options.lua#L6)

Comment: Inside a session running as a command, prepend with lua, i.e. `lua vim.g.autoformat = false`.