# Can I jump to implementation in a C project with coc-clangd?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, filetype-c, clangd

I use NeoVim with coc-clangd. I have a project in C and I use vendor library SPL for STM8S chips. SPL library is in parent directory out of my project.

This is my `compile_flags.txt`:

```
-xc
-std=c99
-Wall
-pedantic
-I.
-I./inc/
-I./src
-I../inc
-I../SPL/inc
-I../SPL/src
-I/usr/local/stow/sdcc-gas/share/sdcc/include
-D_SDCC
-D_SDCC_
-D__SDCC
-D__SDCC__
-DSDCC_VERSION=40000
-D__CLANG
-DSTM8S208 
-DF_CPU=16000000
-Wno-gnu-binary-literal
```

If I input `gd` - go to definition - all works right. But if I input `gi` go to implementation, I get the message `[coc.nvim] implementation not found` .

My question is: Where is the place for configuration of sources files location (with implementations of functions)?

Comment: For the go to implementation to work with clangd you need a `compile_commands.json` file. Maybe [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42567/23502) could help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Neovim clangd to find my files?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42564/how-to-configure-neovim-clangd-to-find-my-files)

Comment: Unfortunately no. But [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42564) led me to another exploration and additional attempts. I will have to rephrase my question.

Comment: In this moment I need to launch clangd (inside NVim) so that I can see its stdout. I haven't been able to persuade Nvim to redirect clangd stdout to a file. I need to view log to debug my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to find the implementation `clangd` need to find a `compile_commands.json` that contains the compilation instruction of the modules (`.cpp`, `.c` file) that contains the implementation.

I believe the `compile_commands.json` must be in the current working directory.

In order to have Vim set the current working directory correctly I'm using the [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) plugin and I put a `.gitignore` in the root of my project hierarchy to guide vim-rooter.

Comment: "[We first check for a compilation database in the directory containing the source file, and then walk up into parent directories until we find one.](https://clangd.llvm.org/design/compile-commands#where-do-compile-commands-come-from)" Out-of-source builds as with CMake can cause problems, though. They are easily fixed with a symlink.

Comment: Furthermore, creating a `.gitignore` file (that's not at all constrained to a repo's root dir) so a plugin can correctly "guess" that dir seems like a very convoluted way to do `:cd <project_root>`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When I replace `compile_flags.txt` with `compile_commands.json` it works. But it is necessary use 'go to definition' no 'go to implementation'.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: I watch different behavior for similar files. It's mystery for me. I have two files in same directory. This two files is described same rules in `compile_commands.json`. Firs is in compilation database, second is not. If I use `gd` over `function1` Nvim go to body of function1 in first file. If I use `gd` over `function2` Nvim go to header of function2 in header file. Now I'm opening manually second source file with `function2` and suddenly the editor behaves differently: I use `gd` over `function2` Nvim go to body of function2 in second file.

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by compilation database if it is not `compile_command.json`. It would be good if you could give a simplified version of the example such that we can reproduce the problem. It could also be that you are hitting a [clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/) weakness that should be reported an issue in the [bug tracker](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues) of the project.